# iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.2

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an iPad Air 2 that is currently running iOS 8.2. When I search for iOS 9 it says that my iPad is up-to-date using 8.2. I plugged the iPad into my computer and looked through iTunes, same issue, says it is up-to-date. I've done a complete reset deleting all settings and media and it still says that it is up-to-date. Has anyone ever seen this issue or know a way around it?

Comment: Maybe just try again later, I'd guess Apple's servers don't know what hit them right now. 6-8am GMT is always a good time to try busy connections, as both US & EU are well out of peak hours.

Answer (score 1):

If OTA upgrades are stuck, plug into iTunes and testore it there.

Comment: The OP already said they had plugged into iTunes.

Comment: @IronCraftMan thanks. Changed check into a flat out restore.